# How can i update all versions of my own module magento using the same file mysql4-upgrade

Tags: magento

I want to know if there's any way to update from all versions (Example: 1.7.1, 1.7.2...) to version 1.8.0 using a single file (Example: mysql4-upgrade-1.7.0-1.8.0) from my own module.
there is a delimiter for that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this in the same file.

When Magento upgrades from one version to another, it will also upgrade all versions in between provided you have the files set up.

So if someone has 1.7.0, and wants to go to 1.8.0, Magento will upgrade from 1.7.0-1.7.1, then 1.7.1-1.7.2 and then from 1.7.0-1.8.0 - providing you include all the files.

Read some more on upgrade paths here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources